# Mensaje sobre imágenes escaladas en GTmetrix

Tags: html, css

No entiendo porque GTmetrix me dice esto sobre mi página

> serve scaled images
>
> The following images are resized in HTML or CSS. Serving scaled images could save 1.1MiB (95% reduction).

No solo debía reducir su resolución sino que me pide que la redimensione y no con HTML o CSS, y lo he hecho previamente y aun asi no funciona, me sigue dando errores.

Fíjense en la primera imagen img/grey.jpg que pone que la reduje de 2896x1944 a 555x373 con CSS pero no es cierto, ya de por sí esa imagen mide 555x373 y le di width 100% a todas las imágenes. ¿Algún consejo por favor?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Ya no se puede reproducir el problema con la imagen que indicas (quizás fue un problema de cacheado de la imagen y por eso la veías con tamaño diferente al real), aunque sí se puede ver el mismo error con otras imágenes ([los resultados se pueden ver en GTmetrix](http://The%20following%20images%20are%20resized%20in%20HTML%20or%20CSS.%20Serving%20scaled%20images%20could%20save%20156.6KiB%20(80%25%20reduction).)):

[image: Captura de GTmetrix]

Ese mensaje ocurre porque las imágenes son más grandes que el tamaño mostrado. En este punto podrías decir "*pero mi sitio sitio web es responsivo/adaptativo, es normal que algunas imágenes se vean más pequeñas que su tamaño real*" y tendrás toda la razón... pero, hay un problema: el tamaño máximo al que se van a mostrar es menor que su tamaño real.

Por ejemplo, las primeras imágenes que te recomienda redimensionar son parte del carrusel:

[image: Carrusel]

Los elementos del carrusel van a tener un ancho máximo de 178 pixels en pantalla grande (el 100% de una posición del carrusel), y un ancho incluso menor en tabletas y dispositivos móviles (al ser responsivo). Pero el ancho real que tienen ahora las imágenes es de 477, 382, 377, 385 y 379 pixels (ver imagen arriba con el error). Por lo que las imágenes SIEMPRE se van a redimensionar.

**Lo ideal sería que el tamaño de la imagen coincidiera con alguno de los tamaños con los que se van a mostrar en la página**. Así evitarás que se manden bytes innecesarios de datos. En el caso del carrusel, como el tamaño más grande que pueden tener es 178px (en pantalla grande), no tiene sentido que las imágenes sean mayores.

Para evitar este problema podrías optar por alguna de estas soluciones:

1. Redimensionar las imágenes para que su tamaño real sea igual o menor que el tamaño máximo que tendrán en la página.
2. Tener diferentes imágenes para los diferentes tamaños y usar [`srcset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/img#attr-srcset) para indicar qué imagen debe usarse con cada resolución/ancho.